# Why did the Minbari surrender in the Battle of the Line?

Tags: babylon-5

After the questioning of Sinclair, it became clear to Minbari they needed to end the battle and the war. But why did Minbari **surrender** to humans instead of accepting Earth's capitulation or simply signing a truce?

Comment: This is brought up again later in the series.  Do you want spoilers, or have you seen the whole thing?  (The answer to this question is in one of those times, but I can't quite remember when... (I have the vague impression it was one of the movies, maybe _In the Beginning_?))

Comment: @Izkata I recall it being addressed fully in Season 3-ish.  It was a two-parter.

Comment: That's the part where they clearly show the whole thing, but it's hinted at throughout the first seasons, showing single scenes and flashbacks starting with (if I remember correctly) the episode with the two interrogators from Earth. The feature movie reuses that footage to show it together with other events happening at that time as well as trying to deliver a more complete picture of the whole conflict.

Comment: @Izkata I have seen the whole thing now, asked the question after watching the movie *In the Beginning*. I understand the reasoning why STOP, but not the reason why SURRENDER, because they had multiple other options. Some of them such that would be more acceptable by the warrior caste.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 26):

The reason behind the surrender of the Minbari fleet at the [Battle of the Line](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_the_Line) is one of the major story arcs in both the first and second seasons of Babylon 5.

Assuming you're familiar with the reasons why the Minbari wanted to end the war...

> (e.g.  in the final moments of the Earth-Minbari War, the Grey Council used a [Triluminary](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Triluminary) as they attempted to interrogate Sinclair, whom they had captured. The Triluminary glowed brightly, indicating that Sinclair had Valen's DNA so the Council assumed that Sinclair had Valen's soul and was the reincarnation of Valen himself (not knowing that Sinclair was in fact **Valen himself**, prior to the events that sent him into the past). The Council thus called an immediate halt to the war, since the fact that Minbari souls were being born in human bodies would mean that Minbari were effectively killing each other - a concept abhorrent to all Minbari.

...then the question can be answered. The Minbari had three choices;

- **Accepting Earth's Surrender**; This would have likely resulted in some sort of occupation or, at the very least the Minbari military caste would have insisted that the Humans cease building warships and withdraw from any expansion or colonisation.
- **Simply disengaging from battle**; This would have resulted in the continued prosecution of violence whenever human spaceships came into contact with Minbari spaceships *or*
- **Minbari surrender**. This resulted in reparations being paid to the Humans (in the form of support for Babylon Project) as well as the Minbari allowing the humans to continue their military R+D, exploration + expansion and allowing a subtle shift of technology from the Minbari to the Humans.

Since the Minbari 'Grey Council' are acutely aware of the prophecy about the coming "[Shadow War](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Second_Shadow_War)" and the need for **all Minbari** to take an active role, crippling the Human race's ability to take part suddenly made no sense. On top of that, they can't risk the war flaring up due to another misunderstanding since it is forbidden for Minbari to attack other Minbari.

A surrender was the only option.

Comment: Good answer. The shadow war prophecy clinched it.

Comment: Also, if they have violated the core tenet of Minbari faith as given by Valen that has been the cornerstone of their society for 1000 years to a nigh-genocidal extent, a great penance is due.

Comment: Minor nitpick here - the triluminary didn't show that he had Valen's soul in particular, just that he had a Mimbari soul.

Comment: @omegacron - Only the Children of Valen make the triluminary glow. Pureblood minbari do not.

Comment: @Omegacron Actually Delenn claims that Sinclair is Valen reborn.  Everything they did later like making him the leader of the Rangers implies they are treating him as having Valen's soul. While it's not clear what indicates that (like glow intensity) we know she triggered it and other humans did too (comics or novels).  So they have 2 new facts. Valen is back and humans are dipping into the Minbari well of Souls explaining their population decline.   So while we may conclude the triluminary is just picking up Sinclair's 5th cousins and great-grandchildren - it is most affected by him.

Answer (score 17):

This is revealed in the series as well as in the feature movie [In the Beginning](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120711/). (Actually **the** reason not to watch it before you're through season 3. There are other minor spoilers for season 4 as well, but those aren't that huge.)

> More or less by accident during an interrogation the Minbari notice that Sinclair has the soul of Valen; that humans possess the souls of Minbari (and in this case not just some random Minbari after all!). Due to the law demanding that no Minbari shall kill another Minbari, they immediately surrender to uphold their ideals without having to tell anyone.

As for "why a surrender?":

> The actual "problem" here has been the fact, that the whole incident and the truth behind it (humans with Minbari souls) has been kept a secret by the religious caste, even inside the Minbari society. The warrior caste never really accepted nor understood the sudden surrender either and there are multiple occassions throughout the early seasons where Minbari soldiers clearly distrust Sinclair (and later Sheridan; especially for him being the "Star-Killer"). There are also several attempts by Minbari soldiers to create distrust between human and Minbari just for the sake of creating another conflict and continue the war.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question why the Minbari surrendered rather than merely ceasing their assault or accepting the President's surrender.

Comment: They couldn't just accept the surrender, because that might have been deemed "not enough" given the incidents leading to the whole conflict. They couldn't just stop it, they had to end the conflict as a whole. An accepted surrender would have been considered a defeat, which possibly wouldn't have avoided any further actions against humankind (compare this to how the Russians "deconstructed" East Germany after WW2, literally taking most things of value). This war however, isn't just about "get us some money back for repairs". It's not the perfect solution, but the only way deemed acceptable.

Comment: Also there may be cultural implications.  Post-Valen the Minbari killing Minbari would be anathema and the aggressor would be always in the wrong.  Not just a negotiated peace would be sufficient to "make up" for the error.

Comment: That's an interesting point, but true. because by surrendering they indirectly admitted their fault, without having to admit anything to the general public. Accepting a surrender they would still have been the side that would have won, making a profit some way or another.

Comment: The only thing lacking in this answer is a depiction as to the scale of guilt the Grey Council felt.  They just launched genocide against a race, and then realized they were slaughtering their own people.  It's unprecedented in Minbari history.  They aren't surrendering because it make military sense, they are doing it because imagine inflicting any more damage or take on any more guilt.  They don't tell anyone because it might destroy Minbari society.

Comment: They had to surrender because they knew the humans would never accept defeat. They were willing to fight to the last person.

Comment: Not surrendering would create a situation where humankind was taken to the brink and "let off" with no explanation - there would be a huge amount of resentment and distrust toward the Minbari for that, which would probably lead to another war later on down the road.  The only way to avoid this would be to make the humans the victors in the conflict, and thus the ones who controlled the situation afterward.  They did so by surrendering and then working with Earth to build the Babylon stations.

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers give a good background and but I feel the most pointed answer is that

> once the Minbari Grey Council knew that Humans had Minbari souls their [Ape Shall Never Kill Ape](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ApeShallNeverKillApe) law (set down by Valen - himself a "Minbari not of Minbari") kicked in.

... and also the whole Prophecy thing too :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though.  The OP knows that they had to stop the war, but there were several less strange options available than surrendering - the OP wants to know why they surrendered instead of doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Also, as further support of the Surrender option, please remember that during the Battle of the Line when Ambassador Kosh was aboard a Minbari ship stated that "the humans are they key." So surrender was the only option for the Grey Council knowing of the coming Shadow War.

Comment: This doesn't explain why they needed to **surrender**.

Answer (score 0):

The humans were not even considering surrender.  The Line was the last line of defense for Earth.  Humans had taken on a "do or die" attitude and would not have surrendered to the invading Minbari.

The only way to stop the killing was for the Minbari to take the first step back.  To simply stop firing on earth ships (without a formal call of surrender) would not have been possible without some kind of explanation as to why the order to cease fire went out.  Surrender **was** that "explanation".

Edited to add...

After Richard's correction to my initial post, I think that although I have no actual supportive references, a plausible reason for the surrender is that the order to kill all humans was given by Delenn, a Grey Council leader for the Religious Cast.  Since the Minbari believed in honor so much (and the Religious Cast being so pious in that regard), it makes sense to me that Delenn would convince the Minbari Grey Council to surrender as a matter of honoring the mistake made by giving the extermination order in the first place.

Comment: Actually EarthGov offered the Minbari a total and unconditional surrender just before the Battle of the Line. It was ignored.

Comment: From the novelisation of "In the Beginning" : *"“Intelligence believes the Minbari intend to bypass Mars and hit Earth directly. They say the attack could come at any time. We have …” Her voice caught for a moment. **“We have continued to broadcast our surrender, and a plea for mercy. They have not responded. We can only conclude … that we stand at the twilight of the Human race.”***

Comment: @Richard thanks for the correction.  I was under the impression that the whole point of The Line was to go out in a blaze of glory or something like that

Comment: The novel, and to some extent  the script both refer to EarthGov offering a surrender on multiple occasions.